# JavaScript innerHTML text linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on a piece of code and wanted to print out a php variable with innerHTML. The code was running fine untill there was a linebreak in the text that I was outputting via innerHTML.

As the next step I tried to use nl2br to replace line breaks with < br / >. The nl2br will replace the line breaks for < br / > but the < br / >s are placed on new lines like this:

```
$authorscomments=nl2br($row[authorscomments]);
```

"this is a comment< br / >
< br / >
comment continued"

This way I still have the line breaks and my jquery breaks. Any suggestions how to pre-treat my text comming from the database so that I can output it via innerHTML?

```
{document.getElementById("nexttable").innerHTML = "<br>AUTHORS COMMENTS <?php echo $authorscomments;  ?>";}
```

Comment: What is it outputting instead?

Comment: @ElGavilan well maybe because it's in the title and its tagged as jquery?

Comment: It is tagged as a jQuery question. Nothing else.

Comment: It does not output anything. I have an event that if I click on a div it will pull data from a database. The page works fine as long as there is text comming with no line breaks. As soon as there are linebreaks none of my jquery works. This is just a snippet from a jquery block that I have posted. The point is: is there any simple way to reformat my text comming from the database so that it ends up being on one line instead of being on multiple lines?

Comment: this is a bigger snippet:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#authorscomments").click(function () {
        $("#nexttable").show(0,function()
{document.getElementById("nexttable").innerHTML = "<br>AUTHORS COMMENTS <?php echo $authorscomments;  ?>";}
                            );
    });
});

Comment: Browsers tend to ignore whitespace as they're not pertinent to the markup. Just replace the line breaks with an empty string on the PHP side. I don't know PHP, but something like `$authorscomments = $authorscomments.replace("\n", "")` to ensure that when it hits the client-side, the javascript string is in-tact

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem in another part of your code. What you have should work assuming that `$authorscomments` is valid.

Comment: When I try to debug with chrome, it says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
As soon as I feed it a string with no line breaks, there are no errors and the site runs like a charm.

Comment: I will try RGraham's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. To pre-treat the text with php before it hits innerHTML this is what I did:

```
 $authorscomments = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "<br />", $authorscomments);
```

This removes all the line breaks and replaces them with < br / > and innerHTML runs just fine at the same time it maintains the formating of the text from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thats very easy in PHP:

```
$authorscomments=nl2br($authorscomment);
```

That replaces all linebreaks with `<br />`.